# How to achieve text right next to page number for the first page only?

Tags: header-footer

[image]

So how would I go about achieving "Last Update ..."

Heres the pdf of the orginal source:

Edit 1: I rechanged the title after edit, because the person who edited didn't understand the question.

[Source](https://github.com/Dongryul-Kim/harvard_notes/blob/master/Math55a/Notes_Math55a.pdf)

Comment: Put it in the footer with a conditional around it `\ifnum\value{page}=1 \textcs{Last Update: \today}\fi`

Comment: I couldn't get that to work on Overleaf. I am getting an undefined control sequence error. Also how would this text appear right next to 1?

Comment: Please add a minimal example which reproduces your problem

Comment: @user203243 Oh, I made a typo.  It's `\textsc` (sc like small caps), not `\textcs`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw and fixed that. However the formatting is a bit off. The "Last Update" would appear above 1.

Answer (score 2):

Load package `fancyhdr` and use command `lfoot` (meaning left foot. You can also have `rfoot`, `cfoot`, & `c/l/rhead`.) as shown in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Loaded for footers.
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Uncomment this line if you don't want the line at the top.

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \rfoot{\small Last update: August 27, 2018}
    \tableofcontents    
    \pagebreak
    \section{First}
    \section{Second}
    \section{Third}
\end{document}
```

---

With `titlepage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Loaded for footers.
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Uncomment this line if you don't want the line at the top.
\title{text}
\author{names}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
        \maketitle
        \thispagestyle{fancy}
        \rfoot{\small Last update: August 27, 2018}
        \tableofcontents
\end{titlepage}    
    \pagebreak
    \section{First}
    \section{Second}
    \section{Third}
\end{document}
```

Comment: **r**foot (meaning **l**eft foot): you might want to correct that.

Comment: Wouldn't this happen on every page? Also page number is now gone?

Comment: Page number doesn't go. Also this is only for the first page. Please compile the example and check again carefully. Thanks @leandriis for the correction.

Comment: Can you try this with a title page? I cannot get it to work when you are dealing with a title page?

Comment: You mean the titlepage environment? Yes sure! You can use the same code. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks that worked! How do I get the header to go way on this page, as I orignally had a header in my code?

Comment: It is very essential to make an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) along with your question for the better understanding. Please add one. I didn't understand your last question regarding header, please elaborate exactly what you want.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to achieve what I want. My problems is not some debugging error.

Comment: Show us what you want by either uploading images or making MWE, otherwise it is very difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you not see the image? Its shows up clear as day to me. Also did you read the post correctly? I have a source.

Comment: "How do I get the header to go way on this page, as I orignally had a header in my code?" This is another (and unclear) question asked by you in the comment. I cannot see a header in the image uploaded by you. Be specific about your queries. Also try to be polite when you are asking for help.

Comment: First of all, I don't understand how I can be more clear? I am providing an image, link, and saying how can I achieve this? Second of all where am I being impolite? Did me saying read the post correctly come out offensively? If so you said "Please compile the example and check again carefully."